# Console APP (.NET Core)

Tags: .net-core

Создаю любой проект .NET Core (asp.net core/console app core)(по умолчанию netcoreapp1.1) -> ошибка компиляции. Отсутствуют все библиотеки. Скачал с официального сайта dotnet-sdk-2.2.101-win-x64 и dotnet-hosting-2.2.0-win, они видны на компьютере (cmd -> dotnet --info), но не видны в VS. Уже несколько дней мучаюсь, не могу найти ответ... Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2017 (все что нужно, установил из коробки, отдельно ставил только dotnet-sdk-2.2.101)

В общем ряд вопросов:

1. Как добавить стандартные библиотеки?
2. Что нужно сделать, чтобы по умолчанию создавалось .NET Core версии 2.2
3. Если я думаю в неверном направлении (пункты 1, 2), что мне следует делать?

Подобной проблемы нет, если создаю проект под .NET Framework.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как мне кажется, .NET Core (или его поддержка) у Вас некорректно установлен или не обновлена студия. У меня, если что, 15.9.4  проблем никаких нет

Comment: У вас не восстановились nuget пакеты. Проверьте окно Output, тип Package Manager

Comment: @Streletz, не знаю как правильно устанавливать. Делаю все по msdn, и консоль ее видит, VS Code также видит, если через консоль проект создать, а VS2017 не видит... Вы указали 15.9.4 - это версия студии?

Comment: @PashaPash, когда для решения восстанавливаю пакеты то пишет, что нечего восстанавливать, все и так есть. Попытался вручную библиотеки в проект добавлять - говорит о несовместимости версий библиотек

Comment: Да, версия студии.